# Modify layout when other activity is called

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want to refresh a textview when next activity is called:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text_status);
if(tv != null){
    tv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.up_to_date));
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
}

v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

but I want to refresh the layout once the next activity is called. Actually i can se how text view changes after the next activity shows up. What I want to do is to modifiy textview once the other activity is called and see the new text in textview when I click back button.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using Activity's onactivityresult Method. Pass your new text through bundles. Get that intent in onactivityresult Method, and set that text to Your textview. See below links for more clarifications : -

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)